# Combine two select SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I would like to know if it is possible to combine these two sql queries in 1 unique query.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT Pseudo FROM Games 
WHERE Time_Format IS NOT NULL 
AND Score IS NOT NULL 
AND Result = 'Win' ORDER BY Date DESC


    SELECT ID_Game,Time_Format,Time,Score,Date 
FROM Games 
WHERE Time_Format IS NOT NULL 
AND Score IS NOT NULL 
AND Result = 'Win' 
AND Pseudo = to the previous result of the other request
ORDER BY Time ASC,Score DESC LIMIT 1
```

Here is an example of data in the **Games** table

```
 INSERT INTO Games(ID_Game, Pseudo, Time_Format,Time, Score,Statut, Result , Date, Date_Fin) VALUES (1,'bob','00:22',22,125,'completed','Win','2022-06-22 13:47:43','2022-06-22 13:47:52'),
(1,'bob2','00:52',52,369,'completed','Lose','2022-06-22 13:40:22','2022-06-22 13:40:22'),
(1,'bob3','00:36',36,650,'completed','Win','2022-06-22 13:22:22','2022-06-22 13:22:22'),
(1,'bob4','00:40',40,378,'completed','Win','2022-06-22 13:12:22','2022-06-22 13:12:22');
```

What I would like to know is to get the best times and scores of the won games but I don't want two identical nicknames in the result

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: It would be nice to help you if you can share sample data and expected result

Comment: What version of mysql do you use that you say that `with` doesn't work? See the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions) that it does work.

Comment: I use the MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 1):

You should use [CTE](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cte-in-sql/) or [subquery](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-subquery/?ref=gcse). I prefer CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Pseudo
    FROM Games 
    WHERE Time_Format IS NOT NULL 
        AND Score IS NOT NULL 
        AND Result = 'Win'
    --ORDER BY Date DESC
)

SELECT ID_Game,Time_Format,Time,Score,Date 
FROM Games 
WHERE Time_Format IS NOT NULL 
    AND Score IS NOT NULL 
    AND Resultat = 'Win' 
    AND Pseudo = (SELECT pseudo FROM cte)
ORDER BY Time ASC, Score DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

, but if CTE is not an option there is a version with subquery:

```
SELECT ID_Game,Time_Format,Time,Score,Date 
FROM Games 
WHERE Time_Format IS NOT NULL 
    AND Score IS NOT NULL 
    AND Resultat = 'Win' 
    AND Pseudo = (
        SELECT DISTINCT Pseudo
        FROM Games 
        WHERE Time_Format IS NOT NULL 
            AND Score IS NOT NULL 
            AND Result = 'Win'
        --ORDER BY Date DESC
    )
ORDER BY Time ASC, Score DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If CTE returns multiple values just replace `AND Pseudo = (SELECT pseudo FROM cte)` with `AND Pseudo IN (SELECT pseudo FROM cte)`

Comment: You don't need the `order by` in the `cte`

Comment: Yes but the with doesn't work in my mysql 5.7

Comment: @Jxprent, so you need a subquery version of my answer, am I right?

Comment: Yes subqueries is a good solution I think, I saw that the CTE is compatible only from mysql 8.0, it doesn't work for me because my host uses version 5.7.

Comment: So can you give me an answer with a subquery ?